# Заполнить массив числами от 1000 до 10000-1

Tags: java, массивы

Добрый день! Создаю массив целочисленных значений, в него через for при старте программы должны заноситься значения от 1000 до 9999 включительно. Затем я случайным образом по нажатию кнопки выбираю и показываю одно из значений. Размер массива ставлю 10000. В результате я часто получаю значение 0, хотя если вывожу весь массив в консоль, то таких значений там нет. Помогите разобраться! В итоге по нажатию кнопки я должен получить только одно 4х-значное число...

**Создаю массив:**

```
public int passArray[] = new int[10000];
```

**Заполняю:**

```
for (int i = 1000; i < passArray.length; i++){             
passArray[i] = i;   
}
```

**Вывожу по нажатию кнопки:**

```
int index;
index = passArray[(int) (Math.random() * passArray.length)];    
System.out.println(Integer.toString(index));
```

В результате то дает число к примеру 3443, то еще раз нажму дает 5534, а еще раз нажимаю и дает 0, может и еще раз дать 0, в общем не могу понять откуда они берутся... Подскажите!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> for (int i = 1000;
> ```

А что по-твоему в массиве в элементах с 0 по 999? Вот как раз 0.

> ```
> int index;
> index = passArray[;    
> System.out.println(Integer.toString(index));
> ```

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString((int)(Math.random() * 9000) + 1000));
```

Answer (score 5):

Массив инициализируется нулями. В массиве 10000 элементов, а вы переинициализируете только 9000.

10% шанс получения ноля.

UPDATE:

```
public int passArray[] = new int[9000];

for (int i = 0; i < passArray.length; i++){             
    passArray[i] = i+1000;   
}
```

Либо как в ответе Qwertiy.

Comment: Я тоже об этом подумал, но как уменьшить размер, чтобы заполнять 9000 начиная с 1000 я не понял.... всю голову уже сломал) подскажите?

Comment: @TimLeyden, так у меня в ответе код без массива.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, как раз его и опробовал... у меня была мысль что до 1000 нули, но как их "отфильтровать" при выборе числа я не знал...и куда подсунуть эту "+1000" тоже так и не додумался)) спасибо! Теперь дает как надо ;)

Comment: да, и такой способ тоже работает! К этому я был ближе всего) Спасибо!